# issues with lapply; subscript out of bounds (and can't figure out where the issue is)

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

Can somebody help!

I am trying to use lapply to loop lstrends() across a large list, yet I received the error and can't think of a fix

Error :

> "Error in data[[var]] : subscript out of bounds"

Code :

```
    ## Test data 
  Tissue=c("Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Tumor","Tumor","Tumor","Tumor")
    GeneY = c(34,12,11,8,53,32,39,80)
    GeneZ = c(4,7,3,9,44,32,56,77)
    GeneX = c(42,54,59,22,35,12,22,40)
    dvList <- c("GeneY", "GeneZ")
    breast = data.frame(Tissue, GeneX,GeneY,GeneZ)

    ## linear regression lapply works fine
    model = lapply(dvList, function(x) {
        lm(substitute(i~GeneX*Tissue, list(i = as.name(x))), data = breast)})
    library(lsmeans)

    ## selecting individual components of the list works fine
    m.lst = as.data.frame(lstrends(model[[2]], "Tissue", var="GeneX"))

    ## lapply for lstrends doesn't work for me
    m.lst = lapply(model, function(x) {
       as.data.frame(lstrends(model, "Tissue", var="GeneX"))})
```

Comment: Take a look at `substitute(i~GeneX*Tissue, list(i = as.name(dvList[[1]])))`. You're including `GeneX` as an independent and dependent variable. The `lm` formula drops `GeneX` when it sees this, and then the `lstrends` function can't find `GeneX` in the variables of model 2

Comment: why would selecting the individual components of the list still work though? ie `model[[2]]` ... have you any suggestion that would get the `lstrends(model[[2]], "Tissue", var="GeneX")` function to loop across the full list?

Comment: I changed the code this morning to remove the `GeneX~GeneX*Tissue` in `lm()` ... unfortunately getting the same error message in `lstrends()` :(

Comment: basically, all I need to do is successfully loop the following code to all elements in the list `as.data.frame(lstrends(model, "Tissue", var="GeneX"))` to obtain a list of data frames or one bound data frame

Answer (score 0):

small typo:

```
m.lst = lapply(model, function(x) {
  as.data.frame(lstrends(x, "Tissue", var="GeneX"))})
```

credit to reddit user suspicious_gardener